# How to run the same scenario multiple times in Selenium Cucumber?

Tags: cucumber

I have not used Example/Data Table to parameterized  the test data, The ask is very straight forward run the same scenario multiple times sequentially.

Comment: Why would you want to do that? Your objective is unclear, therefore it is not possible to provide a good answer to your question.

Comment: Like in testng we have this invocation count, The same thing we want to active here.

Answer (score 2):

Cucumber doesn't have re-run features, but you can simply re-execute the (bash) command to run the tests:

```
for i in {1..10}; do cucumber --tags @rerun; done
```

If you use Maven, Gradle, or something else, just replace *cucumber --tags @tagname* with your command.

Answer (score 2):

In case your objective is to run your scenario multiple times over different data items, you can simply write a Scenario Outline in your gherkin feature file,

Example,

```gherkin
Feature: Sample Feature
  I want to run my scenario multiple times sequentially

Scenario Outline: Verify that scenario runs for all data examples.
Given I am on my application
When I perform action named <actionName>
Then I see reaction named <reactionName>

Examples:
| actionName | reactionName |
| a1         | r1           |
| a2         | r2           |
| a3         | r3           |
| a4         | r4           |
```

The above scenario will run 4 times (once for each example row). Scenario outline is quite helpful in order to test same scenario over different test-data, especially in the case of user interface testing.

Comment: The question is explicit in re-running the same scenario, not to vary the data.